# I want to move the slider smoothly in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using React.js to create the front-end side of a web application that can control home appliances.

What I want to achieve is
I have a slider (LightSliderBar.js) that can change the brightness of the light
When I move the slider, for some reason the slider almost freezes and I can't move it
I want it to move smoothly.

[This is sample video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEC2r5OwUbs)

DiscoverOffice.js

```
const DiscoverOffice = () => {
    
    const [light, setLight] = useState([]);
    
    const getDevices = async(data) => {
      await axios.get('xxx.com',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
          },
        })
        .then(result => {
          setLight(result.data.attributes.light);  
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

return (
    
            {light.map((item,i) => 
            
            <LightSliderBar item={item}/>
            
            )}
    
      );
}
export default DiscoverOffice;
```

LightSliderBar.js

```
const LightSliderBar = ({ item }) => {
    
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const entity_id = item.entity_id;
    const [light, setLight] = useState([]);
    const [brightness_value, setBrightnessValue] = useState(item.brightness);
    
    
    const lightOn = async(data) => {
      console.log("Body sent to server", {
      entity_id: entity_id, 
      brightness: brightness_value
    })
      await axios.post('xxx.com',
        {
          entity_id: entity_id, 
          brightness: brightness_value
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
          },
        })
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Turn on!');
          getDevices();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Turn on Missed!');
        });
    }
    
    const getDevices = async(data) => {
      await axios.get('xxx.com',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
          },
        })
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result.data)
          setLight(result.data.attributes.light);  
          setBrightnessValue(result.data.attributes.light.filter(c => c.entity_id === entity_id).map((item,i) =>  item.brightness)[0]);  
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
    


    useEffect(() => {
      getDevices();
      }, []);

return (
  <div>
      <input className="range-input" type="range" name="speed" min="0" max="100" id="slider"
      value={brightness_value} onChange={lightOn} style={{ background: gradient, }}></input>

  </div>
);
};

export default LightSliderBar;
```

Comment: Where’s the code for `handleSliderChange` function?

Comment: sorry, I missed. fixed

Comment: So every tiny step the slider moves, you `axios.post` to a backend. No wonder it freezes. You need to apply some throttle/debounce strategy to this handler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as mentioned in your comments is most likely the fact, that you are sending an request with every change emited on your input. This is usually solved by delaying request to the start of longer pause.

```js
let changeTimeout 
const onChangeHandler = () => {
  clearTimeout(changeTimeout)
  changeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    lightOn()
  }, 300)
}
```

If you change your onChange function to this it should solve it.

**Explanation**

You have a timer, which resets with every change and at the end of that timer is your request. This means that the request is called only if that timer had time to end. In this case it means after 300ms.

Comment: Thank you but still freezing... I think your answer is collect.. weird...

Comment: your code + onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e)}, right?

Comment: @lion-react there is no reason to pass event, as the function is not using event. I think that `onChange={onChangeHandler}` should work just fine. If not then sure, you can do `onChange={() => onChangeHandler}`